# What is this type?

Tags: haskell, types, constraints

Haskell novice here. I know from [type classes](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) that `=>`means "in the context of". Yet, I can't read the following type, found in module [Statistics.Sample](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.14.0.2/docs/Statistics-Sample.html#v:correlation)

```
(Vector v (Double, Double), Vector v Double) => v (Double, Double) -> Double
```

What constraints are being applied on `v` left of `=>` ?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got "in the context of from". What it means is closer to "If the constraints on the left side are met, a function with the type given of the right side exists".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Data.Vector.Generic.Vector` typeclass takes two type arguments, `v` and `a` where `v :: * -> *` is the type of the container and `a :: *` is the type of the elements in the container.  This is simply a generic interface for the vector types defined in the `vector` package, notably `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector`.

This is essentially saying that the type `v` must be able to hold `(Double, Double)` and `Double`, although not simultaneously.  If you were to use `v ~ Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector` then this works just fine.  The reason is due to the implementation of `correlation`, which uses [`unzip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html#v:unzip).  This function splits a `v (a, b)` into `(v a, v b)`.  Since `correlation` is working on `v (Double, Double)`, it needs the additional constraint that `v` can hold `Double`s.

This generic type is meant to make the `correlation` function work with more types than `Data.Vector.Vector`, including any vector style types that might be implemented in other libraries.

---

I want to stress that these constraints

```
Data.Vector.Generic.Vector v (Double, Double)
Data.Vector.Generic.Vector v Double
```

State that whatever type you choose for `v` is capable of holding `(Double, Double)` and is also capable of holding `Double`.  This is specifying certain prerequisites for your vector type, not the actual contents of the vector.  The actual contents of the vector is specified in the first argument to the `correlation` function.

Comment: So `Foo a, Bar a => a -> Int` expects a to be either of type class Foo or Bar? What about the next part of the signature - why is `v` specified as a tuple, instead of just `v`, for we have already constrained it?

Comment: That would say that `a` has to have implementations for both `Foo` _and_ `Bar`, not either.  The constraint is given with "tuple syntax" because that's the syntax for multiple constraints.  You would actually have to do `(Foo a, Bar a) => a -> Int`, without the parens it won't compile.  What I'm saying above is that `v` is constrained to be a generic `Vector` that is capable of holding `(Double, Double)` or `Double`.  This does not mean that there is a vector whose elements are simultaneously `(Double, Double)` and `Double` (I'm thinking about Python being able to do `[(1.0, 2.0), 3.0]`).

Comment: Python - the C of functional programming.